# How to manipulate the NGINX variable $request_body

Tags: nginx, lua, apache-kafka

I'm using the module ngx_kafka_module (https://github.com/brg-liuwei/ngx_kafka_module) to pass the content of HTTP POST requests coming through nginx to a kafka topic.

It works like a charm but I just found out that there are some important information that nginx sees that are not passed to kafka..

It seems that the module only send the content of the $request_body to the kafka topic while I need also the content of the $remote_add variable .

Is there a way, somehow, to modify $request_body and add the content of $remote_addr to it ?

example :

$request_body = 
"{"type":"VIDEO","uid":"b79eddsddsfb-1sdsd375ad","timestamp":1484580064901,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone) ","device":"mobile"}"

$remote_addr = "192.168.1.1"

after manipulation, $request_body would be :

"{"type":"VIDEO","uid":"b79eddsddsfb-1sdsd375ad","timestamp":1484580064901,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone) ","device":"mobile","ip":"192.168.1.1"}

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That would probably require custom Lua scripting: https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module

Comment: ok, I'm going to check lua